# Nested Form has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am not sure how to proper create a rails form with nested form. I have followed many tutorial but becoming more confused has in what should it be, singular plurials, controller... Here my models

model/event.rb

```
  attr_accessible :description :title, :tag_ids, :locations_attributes
  has_many :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, :allow_destroy => true
```

model/location.rb

```
  attr_accessible :address, :customer_id, :event_id, :latitude, :longitude
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :event
```

controller.rb

```
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    ...
  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    ...
```

view form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :locations do |e| %>
    <%= e.text_field :longitude %>
    <%= e.text_field :latitude %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: locations
```

params send

```
 "locations"=>{"longitude"=>"45.6666",
 "latitude"=>"47.44444665"},
```

Either my relationship are wrong because fields_for doesn't support it, either my controller is not proper, or either rails is just not a great language, or i don't understand it anymore.

Comment: You should at least understand that Rails is *not* a language, it is a framework.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i agreed its a framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You.re nearly there...

event.rb - locations NOT location

```
attr_accessible :description :title, :tag_ids, :locations_attributes
has_many :locations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true
```

Should do it I think

**edit**

And as Valery Kvon says, you need to add

```
@event.locations.build
```

to your controller

Comment: By doing this my field for locations don't appear on the form!

Answer (score 1):

Edward's answer +

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
  @event.locations.build
end
```